# alert a box when URL and tab changed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm beginner in writing extensions for Chrome and I'm solving some *tasks* to learn.

I want to alert the *anything* when I changed tab and/or URL of current tab. For testing I've added following lines to manifest file:

```
"background_page": "background.html",

"permissions": [
    //"activeTab",
    "tabs"
    //"http://*/*",
    //"https://*/*",
    //"https://secure.flickr.com/"
],
```

But in **`chrome://extensions`** page it says

> 'background_page' requires manifest version of 1 or lower.

Full manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Remove unwanted adds",
  "description": "This extension prevents your browser to load adds.",
  "version": "1.0",

  //"background": {
  //  "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
  //},

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ /*"localhost/dental/frontend/patient/signin"*/ "http://someurl" ], // change this to 192.168.5.20/login.html
      //"css": [ "mystyles.css" ],
      "js": [ /*"jquery.js", "myscript.js"*/ "mainscript.js" ]
    }
  ],

  "background_page": "background.html",

  "permissions": [
    //"activeTab",
    //"background",
    //"clipboardRead",
    //"clipboardWrite",
    //"storage",
    "tabs"
    //"http://*/*",
    //"https://*/*",
    //"https://secure.flickr.com/"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    //"default_icon": "img/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

I have also tried this method ([source](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)):

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ /*"localhost/dental/frontend/patient/signin"*/ "http://someurl" ],
      //"css": [ "mystyles.css" ],
      "js": [ /*"jquery.js", "myscript.js"*/ "mainscript.js" ]
    }
  ],
```

in **mainscript.js** I only wrote this line:

```
alert("navigated!");
```

I don't know but this one also not working when I'm navigating to that *someurl*.

So,
1) what's going wrong in my codes
2) what's the best way to solve this *task*?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your full manifest?

Comment: @cyberbit question updated.

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski try removing the comments

Comment: @Cornwell really I'm in stuck... How this happened? o_O what's the role of comments in this type of programs? Can you explain it please?

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski you cannot have comments in json files. Json files are just for data. That being said, I don't know if that will fix your problem

Comment: @Cornwell please answer the question. It solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have comments in json files. Json files are just for data

Answer (score 1):

1) 
**'background_page' requires manifest version of 1 or lower.**

To fix the problem causing this message, your manifest(in respect to background page) should look like this ([source](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)):

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  ...
}
```

Regarding your content script called **mainscript.js not executing**, I would first try to change the matches to cover all urls like this:

```
"matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
```

If the content script starts working, then construct a pattern that would satisfy your needs with the rules mentioned [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns).

2) I suggest you look at [chrome.tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) especially the onCreated, onUpdated and onSelectionChanged events.